# How to edit object (todo) in array? (reactjs)

Tags: reactjs

So I have this to-do list app and I'm working on editing the name of to-do.

When I click on button `edit` I get the value of the name in input field, and when I type something in that field and press enter, it should change/update to-dos' name, but right now it is only adding new to-do.

Here is code I have so far that is working, I deleted all the unsuccessful attempts. I have no more ideas.

```
import React, { useRef, useReducer } from 'react'

function App() {

    const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | any>(null)

    const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        inputRef.current?.value !== "" && dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TODO', payload: inputRef.current?.value })
        inputRef.current && (inputRef.current.value = "")
    }

    const [todo, dispatch] = useReducer((state: any, action: any): any => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'ADD_TODO':
                return [...state, { id: state.length, name: action.payload, isCheck: false }]
            case 'CHECK_TODO':
                return state.filter((item: any, index: any): any => {
                    if (index === action.id) {
                        item.isCheck = !item.isCheck
                    }
                    return item
                })
            case 'DELETE_TODO':
                return state.filter((item: any, index: any) => index !== action.id)
            case 'EDIT_TODO':
                inputRef.current.focus()
                inputRef.current.value = action.payload
                return state
        }
    }, [])

    const todos = todo.map((item: any, index: number) => {
        return (
            <li key={index}>
                <input type="checkbox" checked={item.isCheck} onChange={() => dispatch({ type: "CHECK_TODO", id: index })} />
                {item.name}
                <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'EDIT_TODO', id: index, payload: item.name })}>edit</button>
                <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "DELETE_TODO", id: index })}>x</button>
            </li>
        )
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder='Buy milk'
                    ref={inputRef}
                />
            </form>
            <ul>{todos}</ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

EDIT

Also, new button can be added for submit editing instead of pressing enter, as an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep track of which id/index you are editing so that you can identify whether you are updating or adding value in state. Following code might help. I removed typescript though.

```js
function App() {

  const inputRef = React.useRef(null)
  const [editingIndex, setEditingIndex] = React.useState(null)

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if(inputRef.current && inputRef.current.value !== ""){
      dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TODO', payload: inputRef.current.value, id: editingIndex})
    }
    inputRef.current && (inputRef.current.value = "")
  }

  const [todo, dispatch] = React.useReducer((state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'ADD_TODO':
        setEditingIndex(null)
        const tempState = [...state]
        if(action.id){
          tempState[action.id] = { ...tempState[action.id], name: action.payload }
        }
        else{
          tempState.push({ id: action.id || state.length, name: action.payload, isCheck: false })
        }
        return tempState
      case 'CHECK_TODO':
        return state.filter((item, index) => {
          if (index === action.id) {
            item.isCheck = !item.isCheck
          }
          return item
        })
      case 'DELETE_TODO':
        return state.filter((item, index) => index !== action.id)
      case 'EDIT_TODO':
        inputRef.current.focus()
        inputRef.current.value = action.payload
        return state
    }
  }, [])

  const todos = todo.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <li key={index}>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={item.isCheck} onChange={() => dispatch({ type: "CHECK_TODO", id: index })} />
        {item.name}
        <button onClick={() => {setEditingIndex(index); dispatch({ type: 'EDIT_TODO', id: index, payload: item.name })}}>edit</button>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "DELETE_TODO", id: index })}>x</button>
      </li>
    )
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder='Buy milk'
          ref={inputRef}
        />
      </form>
      <ul>{todos}</ul>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are populating the input with the todo's name when you click the edit button, in the end the `onSubmit` is calling the `handleSubmit` function which calls the `ADD_TODO` reducer.

One thing you can do is set an "edit mode" flag, and change how handleSubmit does it's dispatching and make a new type like `UPDATE_TODO` using the index. Or make that a new function and call the appropriate one based on the update flag, like so:

```
<form onSubmit={editMode ? handleEdit : handleSubmit}>
```